# Add a fixed footer to a resizable body to be able to print it

Tags: html, css

I want to add a footer to the body, but the body has class resize and conatins a dynamic table. I want to add a footer at the end of the body and as the dynamic table increses and when the body starts to be resized vertically the footer moves down too.

I tried the shown css but I did not reach a satisfied output, even when I tried to change the posistion type of the footer I did not find what I am searching for.

```
.resize{
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}


body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
   
    position: inherit;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    
}
```

[image: This is the first part of the body]

[image: Here is when I scroll down the boday]

[image: but when I try to print it this is what it appears]

[image: If I scroll down to the end of the page and right click to print this what appreas "the upper part of the page not visible"]

**I want the footer to be below the terms and conditions even when it expands, it remains in the footer of the page**.
**I want to be able to print the whole body with the footer at the footer even if it will print on 2 pages**

Comment: Given your comments please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find guidance on creating a more well formed question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` instead, depending on whether or not you want the footer to always show.

Comment: I tried both of them, and they did not give me what I was looking for. The point is that the page is resizable so when it expands the effect is good but in the default position before expansion it does not look good.

Comment: Then I don't understand what your intend is based on your question. Could you post an image illustrating what you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use a grid and not have to do a lot

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
}

.footer {
  align-self: end;
  background-color: #ff00ff20;
}
```

```html
<div class="fun">fun</div>
<div class="footer">Sir footer here!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a problem when the page resizes, the point is that after resizing the page I am trying to save it as pdf at this point the footer does disappear if the dynamic table expands with several rows.
And is it possible when I am trying to print/save the PDF of the webpage the footer is duplicated on each page?

Comment: Saving as a PDF is NOT in your question nor is printing - those are both very different from a visual page resize in a browser.  Perhaps ask another question.

Comment: You also mention "table" but as you supplied NO HTML we cannot assume if that is a `<table>` or some other set of elements formatted as a "table".   Perhaps add more HTML including more information on the "dynamic" and how "rows" get added to that.